# Android retrieve listview item clicked in custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm new in Android development, and i have a trouble retrieving both position and item clicked in `ListView`.

I made a custom adapter for my `ListView` with three `TextView`.

**I implemented :**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { ... }
```

I can retrieve without problem what position I clicked, but can't find a solution for what `TextView` I clicked in the row.

`arg2` and `arg3` are always the same value, any idea hot to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: do a little search over google , you will find the answer.

Comment: post your custom adapter code

Comment: my custom adapter is a normal custom adapter and works well. i dont want to use onClick inside this.   my requirement is to find what TextView i clicked inside my activity inside public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {   
if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

**onItemClick** will not work in your case.You want to get values from textview inside the customadapter.The data inside each textview might not be same.so we have to apply setOnClickListener on each textview inside CustomAdapter.

**Problem**

Still we dont know at which position of listview and which textview of that position is clicked.So we set every textview value using **setContentDescription**.

Then on click the already set value get from the textview using **getContentDescription**.

Check out.I made an example for you.Also in future post your code too.

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClicklistener{ 
private static ArrayList<Yourclass> searchArrayList;
Context mycontext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
ViewHolder holder;
static int pos;
public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Yourclass> results) {
    mycontext = context;
    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
   public void clearList() {
    searchArrayList.clear();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YourView, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.firsttextview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firsttextview);
        holder.secondtextview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondtextview);
      holder.thirdtextview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdtextview);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.firsttextview.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).get_text1());//These methods belongs to the Yourclass whose objects are populated based on your records
            holder.secondtextview.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).get_text2());//*get_text2   Replace with your method                               
    holder.thirdtextview.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).get_text3());//*get_text3 Replace with your method

      holder.firsttextview.setContentDescription(holder.firsttextview.getText().toString());
holder.secondtextview.setContentDescription(holder.secondtextview.getText().toString());
  holder.thirdtextview.setContentDescription(holder.thirdtextview.getText().toString());

            holder.firsttextview.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.secondtextview.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.thirdtextview.setOnClickListener(this);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView firsttextview;
    TextView secondtextview;
            TextView thirdtextview;
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getID()) {
    case R.id.firsttextview:
    String des1 =  v.getContentDescription().toString();
    Toast.makeText(mycontext, des1, 5000).show();
        break;
    case R.id.secondtextview:
    String des2 =  v.getContentDescription().toString();
    Toast.makeText(mycontext, des2, 5000).show();
        break;
    case R.id.thirdtextview:
    String des3 =  v.getContentDescription().toString();
    Toast.makeText(mycontext, des3, 5000).show();
    break;
    default:
        break;
    }   

}

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, how i explained, i need to wknow what row in listview i clicked and what element i clicked. i didn'f find how to retrieve position in onClick event. i tryed your code and des1 and des2 contains the value of item i clicked.  something  wrong?

Comment: From where you are populating your textviews ..From Database or simple static data ?

Comment: i fill my array from a database record

Comment: post your database and the helper class used for populating custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

In your list `adapter` put `onClickListener` on `textview` and you'll get its value on touch

I am putting only related code here, try this, it worked for me

```
viewHolder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
viewHolder.userName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView text=(TextView)v;
        if(text!=null){
            System.out.println("\nUsername :"+text.getText().toString());                   
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps,Cheers!...